# Why do I get an 'Invariant Violation' error when using KeyboardAvoidView?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having issues with my content being pushed up and smashed together when the keyboard is present in my react native app.  I am trying to use KeyboardAvoidView to fix this but I keep getting an Invariant Violation error.  This error only occurs when I use KeyboardAvoidView.  When I switch back to using just View it goes away.  Does anyone know how to get KeyboardAvoidView to work correctly?

```
        import React, {Component} from 'react';
        import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
        import {View, StyleSheet, Text, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, Image, ActivityIndicator, KeyboardAvoidView} from 'react-native';
        import {connect} from "react-redux";            
        import Header from '../../components/Header/Header';
        import Loader from "../../components/Login/Loader";
        import {loadCustomerOrderDetails} from '../../actions/AppActions'
        import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
        import {createIconSetFromIcoMoon} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
        import selection from '../../selection';

        class Home extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.props.dispatch(loadCustomerOrderDetails(this.props.customerId));
            }

            render() {
                const {isLoading, details} = this.props.customerData;
                const {invoices, unsubmittedOrders, itemIssues, deliveryStats} = details;

                return (
                    <KeyboardAvoidView style={styles.wrapper} behavior="padding" enabled>

                        <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/loginBG.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>

                            <View>
                                <Image style={styles.mblogo} source={require('../../assets/mb_logo.png')} />
                            </View>

                            {isLoading &&
                                <ActivityIndicator
                                    style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
                                    animating={true}
                                    size='large'
                                />
                            }

                        </ImageBackground>
                        <Header style={styles.header}/>
                    </KeyboardAvoidView>
                );
            }
        }

        Home.propTypes = {
            customerData: PropTypes.object,
            customerId: PropTypes.string,
        }

        function mapStateToProps(state) {
            const {customerData, app} =  state;
            return {
                customerData: customerData,
                customerId: app.customerId
            };
        }

        export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

[image]

Comment: can you show your importing from 'react-native' part of code

Comment: Yes I have added it now.  Sorry I don't know how I forgot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html) not KeyboardAvoidView.